# How to import Large flat file into SQL SERVER 2016?

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis, tpc

I have a tpcds dsdgen generated data about 100GB, and each dat file is around 20GB+,
I have exhaustively searched how to load flat file into sql-server 2016, and i tried importing it using SSIS package and enabled fast parse on all the decimal fields.
Still it takes lot of time to load into a table. Its taking 24hrs and continuing and just loaded 9,700,000 records of a table only,

is the above the ideal way, or what could be the problem.

please help me, Iam stuck with this problem and also new to MSSQL world.

Comment: SSIS can load millions of rows per minute. Make sure you are using an OLE DB destination with the fast load option with a non-zero maximum insert commit size and table lock options. Ideally, minimal indexes on the target table too.

Comment: i have an OLE DB destination , i have enaled fast-load(the second option in the dropdown), i removed constraint check, i kept table lock, and increased batch size and max insert commit size, still, this issue is prevaling

Comment: How many indexes on the table? What is the commit size?

Comment: Are the files, the SQL Server and the SSIS runtime all on the same host? Are the data in the files in a known order?

Comment: There is no indexes, and commit size is 2000000000, batch size is 100000,

Thanks for the help, i cleared cache, and buffer for every 5min. Things was sorted, but i still dont know wether that solved the problem.
Could anyone explain?